# In VBA in Words, how do you input the character "█" with the font "Courier New"?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Using VBA in excel and words module enabled, I want to change my font (I set the Font.Name to "Courier New") with the character "█" U+2588. However, VBA keeps using the Font.NameFarEast variable instead. How can I change this behaviour?

Example code (Excel 2016):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Export()
    Dim objWord As New Word.Application
    Dim objDocument As Document

    Set objDocument = objWord.Documents.Add
    objDocument.Content.InsertAfter "test"  'Will be Courier New
    objDocument.Content.InsertAfter ChrW(&H2588)  'Will be DengXing

    With objDocument
        With .Content
            .Font.Name = "Courier New"
            '.Font.NameFarEast = "Courier New"  'Error 5844 (i.e. "FarEast font does not exists")
        End With
        .SaveAs Filename:=CurDir() & "\Sample.docx"
    End With

    objDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    objWord.Quit
    Debug.Print "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any problems with your code here. This may be an issue with the settings in your Normal.dotm file, which is the source of files created with Documents.Add.

Comment: Best use of Word's object model, IMO, would be to have this character stored in a Building Block / AutoText entry and insert that. The formatting, ideally, would be handled by use of a style in the original text for the entry. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock